# Unable to get memory snapshots in Adobe Scout from a remote SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, memory-profiling, adobe-scout

**Background**

I have been using Adobe Scout to profile my swf for a while (I was only interested in knowing the CPU usage and execution time).  And, now I would like to take a look at the memory allocation in this swf.  Having checked all the checkboxes that relate to memory allocation in Scout still wouldn't record memory allocations.  In fact, it even asks me to enable the *Actionscript Memory Allocations" setting.

However, I have tried to look for a specific tag-value-pair in .telemetry.cfg online about that "actionscript memory allocation" flag but had no luck.

As you can see from the screen shots, "Actionscript Memory Allocation" is disabled.

**Sofware & Hardware Environment**
Adobe Flex SDK 3.3
Adobe Flash Builder 4.0
SWF Scout Enabler by Erickson

**Screen Shots**

[image][image][image]

**.telemetry.cfg** 

`TelemetryAddress = 160.x.y.z:7934 

SamplerEnabled = true 

CPUCapture = true 

DisplayObjectCapture = true 
 
Stage3DCapture = true`

**Question**
What do I need in order to enable the "actionscript memory allocation" setting in Scout? 
*As you can see from the screen shots, "Actionscript Memory Allocation" is disabled.*

Thanks very much.  Any form of help is appreciated.

Comment: Does it work when you do it from a local Swf ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please allow me to answer my own question and keep this question as I believe someone out there is going to need this piece of information to make remote (memory) 'scouting' work.

In *.telemetry.cfg*, you will need to add this tag-value-pair.

```
ScriptObjectAllocationTraces = true
```

Reference
[1] http://forums.adobe.com/message/5785887